# python boolean quest. for if statement

Tags: python, if-statement, boolean

I tried this... but it doesn't work

```
question = input("do you want the program to start? Type Y/y to start: ")
y = TRUE
Y = TRUE

if(question == TRUE):
     run statements
else:
```

what am i doing wrong? this doesn't work.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: This code won't even run.  There's nothing after the `else:` clause.

Comment: oh i know, i didnt send the full code, my problem is when I do something like this it would say y = 0 and don't run.

Comment: I'm just trying to get the user to say y or Y and then run true rather then running my else statements that i didnt put on here.

Answer (score 0):

The boolean is `True` in Python, not `true` or `TRUE`. In any case, this doesn't do what you expect it to. This is what I'd do.

```
question = input("...")
if question.lower() == 'y': # or `question in ('y','Y'):` or `question.upper() == "Y":` or `question.casefold() == 'y':` or................
    do_things
else:
    handle_it
```

What you had written assigns the variables `y` and `Y` to some (undefined) variable `TRUE`. This will trigger a `NameError` since there is no such variable `TRUE`. If you had done:

```
y = True
Y = True
```

It still wouldn't have done what you wanted, since your input (fed into the variable `question`) is a string and those are variables. You could have done that with `if globals()[question]` but that's really bad practice, and COMPLETELY unnecessary in this situation.

As a side note -- there's never a reason to type `== True`. `if foo` will evaluate to `True` or `False`, which will fulfill the conditional on its own. It just does a needless compare :)

Comment: I tried this and it saysTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Chan\Desktop\encryption\dict program.py", line 35, in <module>
    if (question.lower() == y):
NameError: name 'y' is not defined

Comment: @user3294540 You didn't do what I did, you did `if question.lower() == y`. I did `if question.lower() == "y"`. Remember any input you get from the user will be a string, so you need to test for a string. I edited my answer with a little more general information.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your specific question, it is not working because of these issues:

1. `TRUE` is not a defined variable in python. `True` is.
2. `question == TRUE` won't work. See 1.
3. `run statements` isn't real code.
4. You need to put something in your `else:` block.

   EDIT:
5. `question` can never become `True` in this code. –  @adsmith

   NOTE:

Just trying to be comprehensive with my coverage.

Comment: not to mention `question` can never become `True` in this code, which is the biggest bit of conflabulation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably want to use code something along these lines:

```
answer = raw_input("Do you want the program to start? Type Y/y to start: ")

if answer[0].lower() != "y":  # first character not a "Y" or "y"?
     exit()

rest of program...
```

Answer (score -1):

1) You have five (5) spaces indenting your `if` clause. Should follow Generally Accepted Python Practices (GAPP) ;) (Yes, I just made this up. It may or may not become a thing :p) you should use four (4) spaces.

2) Try adding `pass` after `else:`

```
else:
    pass
```

3) In Python, `case` matters.  As such, `boolean` testing must be `True` or `False` (or 1/0 :p)

4) Don't you mean Y/N?  Not Y/y?